# Data analysis over multiple dataframes? Panels or Multi-index?

Tags: pandas, panel, multi-index

When I extract data for multiple stocks using  web.DataReader, I'm getting a panel as the output.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt
import re



startDate = '2010-01-01'
endDate = '2016-09-07'  
stocks_query = ['AAPL','OPK']


stocks = web.DataReader(stocks_query, data_source='yahoo',
                  start=startDate, end=endDate)
stocks = stocks.swapaxes('items','minor_axis')
```

Leading to an output of :

```
Dimensions: 2 (items) x 1682 (major_axis) x 6 (minor_axis)
Items axis: AAPL to OPK
Major_axis axis: 2010-01-04 00:00:00 to 2016-09-07 00:00:00
Minor_axis axis: Open to Adj Close
```

A single dataframe of the panel looks like this

`stocks['OPK']`

```
            Open  High   Low  Close      Volume  Adj Close  log_return  \
Date                                                                     
2010-01-04  1.80  1.97  1.76   1.95    234500.0       1.95         NaN   
2010-01-05  1.64  1.95  1.64   1.93    135800.0       1.93   -0.010309   
2010-01-06  1.90  1.92  1.77   1.79    546600.0       1.79   -0.075304   
2010-01-07  1.79  1.94  1.76   1.92    138700.0       1.92    0.070110   
2010-01-08  1.92  1.94  1.86   1.89     62500.0       1.89   -0.015748
```

I plan to do a lot of data manipulation across all dataframes adding new columns. comparing two dataframes etc. I was recommended to looking into multi_indexing, as panels are being deprecated.

This is my fist time working with panels. 
If I want to add a new column to both dataframes (AAPL, OPK), I had to do something like this:

```
for i in stocks:
        stocks[i]['log_return'] = np.log(stocks[i]['Close']/(stocks[i]['Close'].shift(1)))
```

If multi_indexing is indeed recommended for working with multiple dataframes, how exactly would I convert my dataframes into a form I can easily work with? 
Would I have one main index, with the next-level being the stocks, and the columns would be contained within each stock?

I went through the docs, which gave many examples using tuples o which I didn't get or examples using single dataframes. 
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html

So how exactly do I convert my panel into a multi_index dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to extend [@piRSquared's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43054718/5741205) with some examples:

```
In [40]: stocks.to_frame()
Out[40]:
                              AAPL         OPK
Date       minor
2010-01-04 Open       2.134300e+02        1.80
           High       2.145000e+02        1.97
           Low        2.123800e+02        1.76
           Close      2.140100e+02        1.95
           Volume     1.234324e+08   234500.00
           Adj Close  2.772704e+01        1.95
2010-01-05 Open       2.146000e+02        1.64
           High       2.155900e+02        1.95
           Low        2.132500e+02        1.64
           Close      2.143800e+02        1.93
...                            ...         ...
2016-09-06 Low        1.075100e+02        9.19
           Close      1.077000e+02        9.36
           Volume     2.688040e+07  3026900.00
           Adj Close  1.066873e+02        9.36
2016-09-07 Open       1.078300e+02        9.39
           High       1.087600e+02        9.60
           Low        1.070700e+02        9.38
           Close      1.083600e+02        9.59
           Volume     4.236430e+07  2632400.00
           Adj Close  1.073411e+02        9.59

[10092 rows x 2 columns]
```

but if you want to convert it to MultiIndex DF, it's better to leave the original pandas_datareader Panel as it is:

```
In [38]: p = web.DataReader(stocks_query, data_source='yahoo', start=startDate, end=endDate)

In [39]: p.to_frame()
Out[39]:
                        Open        High         Low       Close       Volume   Adj Close
Date       minor
2010-01-04 AAPL   213.429998  214.499996  212.380001  214.009998  123432400.0   27.727039
           OPK      1.800000    1.970000    1.760000    1.950000     234500.0    1.950000
2010-01-05 AAPL   214.599998  215.589994  213.249994  214.379993  150476200.0   27.774976
           OPK      1.640000    1.950000    1.640000    1.930000     135800.0    1.930000
2010-01-06 AAPL   214.379993  215.230000  210.750004  210.969995  138040000.0   27.333178
           OPK      1.900000    1.920000    1.770000    1.790000     546600.0    1.790000
2010-01-07 AAPL   211.750000  212.000006  209.050005  210.580000  119282800.0   27.282650
           OPK      1.790000    1.940000    1.760000    1.920000     138700.0    1.920000
2010-01-08 AAPL   210.299994  212.000006  209.060005  211.980005  111902700.0   27.464034
           OPK      1.920000    1.940000    1.860000    1.890000      62500.0    1.890000
...                      ...         ...         ...         ...          ...         ...
2016-08-31 AAPL   105.660004  106.570000  105.639999  106.099998   29662400.0  105.102360
           OPK      9.260000    9.260000    9.070000    9.100000    2793300.0    9.100000
2016-09-01 AAPL   106.139999  106.800003  105.620003  106.730003   26701500.0  105.726441
           OPK      9.310000    9.540000    9.190000    9.290000    3515300.0    9.290000
2016-09-02 AAPL   107.699997  108.000000  106.820000  107.730003   26802500.0  106.717038
           OPK      9.340000    9.390000    9.160000    9.330000    2061200.0    9.330000
2016-09-06 AAPL   107.900002  108.300003  107.510002  107.699997   26880400.0  106.687314
           OPK      9.320000    9.480000    9.190000    9.360000    3026900.0    9.360000
2016-09-07 AAPL   107.830002  108.760002  107.070000  108.360001   42364300.0  107.341112
           OPK      9.390000    9.600000    9.380000    9.590000    2632400.0    9.590000

[3364 rows x 6 columns]
```

How to work with a MultiIndex DF:

```
In [46]: df = p.to_frame()

In [47]: df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, ['AAPL']], :]
Out[47]:
                        Open        High         Low       Close       Volume   Adj Close
Date       minor
2010-01-04 AAPL   213.429998  214.499996  212.380001  214.009998  123432400.0   27.727039
2010-01-05 AAPL   214.599998  215.589994  213.249994  214.379993  150476200.0   27.774976
2010-01-06 AAPL   214.379993  215.230000  210.750004  210.969995  138040000.0   27.333178
2010-01-07 AAPL   211.750000  212.000006  209.050005  210.580000  119282800.0   27.282650
2010-01-08 AAPL   210.299994  212.000006  209.060005  211.980005  111902700.0   27.464034
2010-01-11 AAPL   212.799997  213.000002  208.450005  210.110003  115557400.0   27.221758
2010-01-12 AAPL   209.189995  209.769995  206.419998  207.720001  148614900.0   26.912110
2010-01-13 AAPL   207.870005  210.929995  204.099998  210.650002  151473000.0   27.291720
2010-01-14 AAPL   210.110003  210.459997  209.020004  209.430000  108223500.0   27.133657
2010-01-15 AAPL   210.929995  211.599997  205.869999  205.930000  148516900.0   26.680198
...                      ...         ...         ...         ...          ...         ...
2016-08-24 AAPL   108.570000  108.750000  107.680000  108.029999   23675100.0  107.014213
2016-08-25 AAPL   107.389999  107.879997  106.680000  107.570000   25086200.0  106.558539
2016-08-26 AAPL   107.410004  107.949997  106.309998  106.940002   27766300.0  105.934466
2016-08-29 AAPL   106.620003  107.440002  106.290001  106.820000   24970300.0  105.815591
2016-08-30 AAPL   105.800003  106.500000  105.500000  106.000000   24863900.0  105.003302
2016-08-31 AAPL   105.660004  106.570000  105.639999  106.099998   29662400.0  105.102360
2016-09-01 AAPL   106.139999  106.800003  105.620003  106.730003   26701500.0  105.726441
2016-09-02 AAPL   107.699997  108.000000  106.820000  107.730003   26802500.0  106.717038
2016-09-06 AAPL   107.900002  108.300003  107.510002  107.699997   26880400.0  106.687314
2016-09-07 AAPL   107.830002  108.760002  107.070000  108.360001   42364300.0  107.341112

[1682 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: Ah, yeah I was playing around with PIR's answer and was trying to figure out how to transpose the dates with the stocks names. There is a dataframe method to do that right (I can't remember it off the top my head). 
I'm going to play around with your answer  a bit more and see if run into any problems.

Comment: According to the docs, when I type `df.columns` I'm supposed to see all the index levels, but I'm only seeing the columns in this case. 
`[29]: df.columns
Out[29]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'bar', u'baz', u'foo', u'qux'], [u'one', u'two']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]],
           names=[u'first', u'second'])`


Above is the what's shown in the docs. But in my case, I'm seeing only the column names; Does that mean this is  not a multi-index  df?

`Index(['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Adj Close'], dtype='object')`

Comment: @moondra, it is a MultiIndex DF - try this `df.index.names`

Answer (score 2):

You're going to love this one

```
stocks.to_frame()
```